# validate_presence_of field_name if params exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want validate presence of a object attribute if params exist or on a specific action. This is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(current_user, :url => { :controller => "users", :action => "request_permissions_callback"} , :method => :get) do |f| %>
 <%= f.input :external_email %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :external, :value => true %>
 <%= f.button :submit %>    
<% end %>
```

On my model I don't know if this approach is correct:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :external_email
  validates_presence_of :external_email, :if => :external
  attr_accessor :external
end
```

Or other approach is how can I validate presence of `:external_email` only on action `request_permissions_callback`?

Thanks!

Comment: your approaches are working or not??

Comment: My aproach is not working!. I can update my `external_email` field without fill this field on form. Thank you!

Comment: then whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :external_email
  attr_accessor :external
  attr_accessible, :external_email, :external
  validates_presence_of :external_email, :if => :external
end
```

It is also necessary to add the virtual attribute to `attr_accessible`

Thank you!